# Parse server "port is already in use"

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I've been using my past server for the past week, had no significant issues, however I've recently ran into some problems when I've tried to start it. I called `pm2 start ecosystem.json` and found that my app was having problems connecting to the server. I ran the same command, but with logs this time (`pm2 start ecosystem.json --no-daemon`) and saw that it was continuously failing to spin up the parse-server:

`13:50:14 parse-wrapper-0 Unable to listen on port 1337. The port is already in use.`

I'm using Ubuntu and pm2 - any idea how to solve this/free up the port/change the port?

ecosystem.json :

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "parse-wrapper",
    "script"      : "/usr/bin/parse-server",
    "watch"       : true,
    "merge_logs"  : true,
    "cwd"         : "/home/parse",
    "env": {
      "PARSE_SERVER_CLOUD_CODE_MAIN": "/home/parse/cloud/main.js",
      "PARSE_SERVER_DATABASE_URI": "mongodb://parse:MyPassword!@www.appname.co:27017/AppName?ssl=true",
      "PARSE_SERVER_APPLICATION_ID": "FbwFDttus57ozEoEpCxEfDzDBANWdVRjacDY2aQt",
      "PARSE_SERVER_MASTER_KEY": "bLa7cNZqijshmRiPnlrb9qzzf0qqI4zi3A0",
      "PARSE_SERVER_CLIENT_KEY": "f1HKq8yyf6Qz2dUqoh3DuwZwMUDhPV2Xqa52",
      "PARSE_SERVER_REST_API_KEY": "qP3XN29gqs1QWFEnUSnlGcW8pJA8dB1fYd6z",
      "PARSE_SERVER_FILE_KEY": "6a2db63d-4e16-96e2-703953ac214f",
      "PARSE_SERVER_PUSH": '{"ios":{"pfx":"pushCert.p12","bundleId":"com.xxx.yyy","production":false}}'
    }
  }]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You have two options, change the port of the application you are trying to start with p2m or turn off the application that use the port 1337 (or change the port there). You can find the application that uses port 1337 by running

`lsof -i :1337`

Comment: changing the port of the application as its mostly treated as a "black box". I tried running your command, it just printed an empty line. Any ideas?

Comment: I have no clue, I'll try to run p2m and see what I get. Are you able to paste the content of  ecosystem.json, I am thinking it might have the port for your app.

Comment: just added it, don't think it has any relation to the error + can't find any port over there

Comment: right, maybe the port is set in ```/home/parse/cloud/main.js```

Comment: nope, that is a file for "cloud code", if anything it might be in one of the other scripts

Comment: i think there might be a key i can add in the ecosystem.json to change the port, i'll check that

Comment: was able to switch ports, but i'm getting a different problem now. I pasted my log here if it interests you https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/2445

Comment: If it printed an empty line that means no applications are running on port 1337 I believe.